# how to make a function that bind a button to the same function

Tags: jquery, bind

[see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sq52pgyc/)

I'm reposting this because I may have not described this correctly.
I'm trying to add a button to a table within a form that create a new row for input, and at the end of the new row, it should display another button to insert another line, and so on.

I try to achieve this by calling the function from itself to add the new button when the line is created and hide the previous one.

Here's my actual code

```
  if(!$('input[name="addressee\\[line3\\]"').length) {
    add_button(3);
  } else if (!$('input[name="addressee\\[line4\\]"').length) {
    add_button(4);
  }

  function add_button(number) {
    let btn = $('<input/>', {
      'type': 'button',
      'value': 'add line',
      'data-number': number,
      'on': {
        click: function() {
          let row  = $('<tr><td><label for="line' + number + '">Addresse(suite)</label></td><td><input name="line' + number + '" style="width: 300px"/></td></tr>');
          $('input[name="addressee\\[line' + (number - 1) + '\\]"').closest('tr').after(row);
          if ($(this).data('number') == '3') {
            add_button(4);
          }
          $(this).hide();
        }
      }
    });
    $('input[name="addressee\\[line' + (number - 1) + '\\]"').after(btn);
  }
```

and here is the HTML, it's just a simple table

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="line2">Adresse</label>
      </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" name="addressee[line2]" value="250 rue des granges" style="width: 300px"><br>          
     </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It create the first line, but the button is not showing on the second when it's created.

[see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sq52pgyc/)

I've tried many things, but it's the best I've managed to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful on your add_button fonction, when you set your next functions when button is clicked

```
function add_button(number) {
  let btn = $('<input/>', {
    'type': 'button',
    'value': 'add line',
    'data-number': number,
    'on': {
      click: function() {

        // \/ HERE YOU DON'T SET "addressee[line..]" BUT JUST "line" ON THE NAME OF THE INPUT

        let row  = $('<tr><td><label for="line' + number + '">Addresse(suite)</label></td><td><input name="line' + number + '" style="width: 300px"/></td></tr>');

        // /\

        $('input[name="addressee\\[line' + (number - 1) + '\\]"').closest('tr').after(row);
        if ($(this).data('number') == '3') {
          add_button(4);
        }
        $(this).hide();
      }
    }
  });
  $('input[name="addressee\\[line' + (number - 1) + '\\]"').after(btn);
}
```

Comment: so silly, thanks it works. at least I was on the right track, and It made me think on how to ask question the right way. Thanks a lot.